# Database error with migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate users and a few other entities from a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8 with the built-in migration modules and Migrate Plus.  I have added a database array in settings.php but something is missing to get the migrations to "see" the right database. I am getting this error.

[Mon May 11 22:22:56.025896 2020] [php7:error] [pid 6389:tid 140003403929344] [client 62419] PHP Fatal error:  Method Drupal\user\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\Role::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Drupal\migrate\Exception\RequirementsException: No database connection configured for source plugin d7_user_role in /var/www//web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Unicode.php on line 595, referer:

I have tried adding

```
shared_configuration:
 source:
   key: database_key
```

But it did not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to troubleshoot this remotely but there are a couple of things you can try to get connected to your source DB.

1. In your group's `shared_configuration.source` config you can manually add a `database` key with the same DB setting array properties that the migration module [also looks for](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21source%21SqlBase.php/function/SqlBase%3A%3AsetUpDatabase/8.8.x). For example:

```
shared_configuration:
 source:
   key: database_key
    database:
      driver: mysql
      username: user
      password: pass
      ...
```

2. Use the [migrate update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) to template out an initial working migration config rather than manually add your source DB. For example, run: `drush migrate:upgrade --legacy-db-key database_key ...`.